# Adding .dll to a VS 2012 Setup Project

Tags: c#

My project has a .dll as a Reference which is (HtmlAgilityPack) and when i do a Setup Project, it returns an error that

```
See the end of this message for details on invoking 
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

************** Exception Text **************
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'HtmlAgilityPack,
Version=1.4.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=bd319b19eaf3b43a' or one of its   
dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

How can i solve this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is only a reference dll and not suppose to be installed then you can just add it to the root of you execution file where yourapplication.exe is available.

for making it as a single setup file you can get the setup maker of Visual Studio or use other available software.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that the required DLLs are either already present on the target system or are installed along with your application. This error message means that a required DLL was not found and thus could not be loaded.

If you use a Visual Studio Setup project to install your application, look under "Dependencies" whether the required DLLs are present and are also included with the setup.

Comment: Yes i know, in 2008 the .dll was added automatically
But in 2012, I don't know how to add it

Comment: My Question is how to add the .dll

Comment: There are no setup projects in 2012 anymore. Only WiX and InstallShield LE. Which one?